# How to get first repeated object from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I have an array of objects like this:

```js
const result = [
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Lemon', Origin: 'Spain' },
  { ProductName: 'Avocado', Origin: 'Chile' }
];

// Expected output since there are duplicates:
const output = [{ ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' }]
```

Like shown above, there might be duplicates in the array (but it's not a must). That's why I'd like to:

1. check if there are duplicates in the array
2. if yes: create new array with only duplicates (show duplicate only 1x, even if there might be 2 or 3 duplicated in const result)
3. if no: leave const result as is

By now, I tried to modify a code, which does the opposite: it finds unique (not duplicated) objects in the result-array. But I just can't get it work. Maybe it's just a wrong approach? Any help is appreciated!

```js
const endresult = result
  .map(e => e.ProductName)
  .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
  .filter(e => result[e])
  .map(e => result[e]);
```

Comment: Loop over every element (you can ignore the last), and for every element check all elements that come after it (needs a second loop) if there's an object with the same product. If so, push that element into a new array (needs a check if there's already an object with the same product). At the end you have either an array of duplicated values, or an empty one because there are no dupes in the source.

Comment: Please show your expected output. Do you expect `out = [{ ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' }]` or `out = [{ ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },{ ProductName: 'Lemon', Origin: 'Spain' },{ ProductName: 'Avocado', Origin: 'Chile' }]`

Comment: @pilchard: The expected output is: out = [{ ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const result = [
  {ProductName: "Orange", Origin: "Italy"},
  {ProductName: "Orange", Origin: "Italy"},
  {ProductName: "Lemon",  Origin: "Spain"},
  {ProductName: "Avocado",Origin: "Chile"},
  {ProductName: "Orange", Origin: "Italy"}
];

function getDuplicatesOrAll(arr) {
  const duplicates = arr
    .reduce((acc, p, i) => {
      const isDuplicate = i !== result.findIndex(({ProductName}) => ProductName === p.ProductName);
      if (isDuplicate) {
        const wasAlreadyMet = acc.some(({ProductName}) => ProductName === p.ProductName);
        if (!wasAlreadyMet) {
          acc.push(p);
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    
  return duplicates.length ? duplicates : arr;
}

console.log( getDuplicatesOrAll(result) );
```

Maybe easier to read using your method to work with names only:

```js
 const result = [
  {ProductName: "Orange", Origin: "Italy"},
  {ProductName: "Orange", Origin: "Italy"},
  {ProductName: "Lemon",  Origin: "Spain"},
  {ProductName: "Avocado",Origin: "Chile"},
  {ProductName: "Orange", Origin: "Italy"}
];

function getDuplicatesOrAll(arr) {
  const duplicates = arr
    .map(({ProductName}) => ProductName)
    .reduce((acc, name, i, final) => {
      const isDuplicate = i !== final.indexOf(name);
      if (isDuplicate) {
        const wasAlreadyMet = acc.includes(name);
        if (!wasAlreadyMet) {
          acc.push(name);
        }
      }
      return acc;
    }, [])
    .map(name => result.find(({ProductName}) => ProductName === name));

  return duplicates.length ? duplicates : arr;
}

console.log( getDuplicatesOrAll(result) );
```

Comment: Ok, so everything works when I have duplicates in the result-array. But when there are no duplicates I get an empty array. I suppose we need to include an additional if-else statement? What do you think?

Comment: @Ewax_Du I missed that part. I edited the code, and made a function to contain this logic

Comment: Thanks. I tested the code and it works. I marked your answer as the solution because you gave me 2 possible code snippets and this made it easier for me - as a beginner - to follow. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Can be accomplished using `Array#filter` and `Array#some`.

- Filter the array using `Array#filter` and for each object check if that object is repeated.
- For a object its repetition can be checked using `Array#some`.
- If duplicates are found return that, else return the original array

```js
const result = [
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Lemon', Origin: 'Spain' },
  { ProductName: 'Avocado', Origin: 'Chile' },
];

const getDups = (arr) => {
  const seen = new Set
  const dups = arr
    .filter((o1, i)=> arr.slice(i+1)
                          .some(o2 => o1.ProductName === o2.ProductName &&
                                      o1.Origin === o2.Origin)           
                       &&      
                      !arr.slice(0, i)
                         .some(o2 => o1.ProductName === o2.ProductName &&
                                      o1.Origin === o2.Origin));
  if(dups.length){
    return dups;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(getDups(result));
```

Comment: @blex thanks for spotting that bug, fixed it now!

Answer (score 0):

Make two object of unique items and duplicates, then check if duplicate exists make it array and return it.

```js
const result = [
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Lemon', Origin: 'Spain' },
  { ProductName: 'Avocado', Origin: 'Chile' }
];

function duplicateFinder(array){
  const cache = {};
  const duplicates = {};
  let endResult = [];
  array.forEach(e=>{
    cache[e.Origin]?
      duplicates[e.Origin] = e:
      cache[e.Origin] = true;
  })
  Object.keys(duplicates).forEach(e => {
      endResult.push(duplicates[e])
  })
  return endResult.length ? endResult : array;
}

console.log(duplicateFinder(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `Array.prototype.sort()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` method.

- First, sort the array by `ProductName`.
- Then use filter method for duplicates.
- At last, if no duplicate is found then return the original array; otherwise, filtered duplicate result.

```js
const result = [
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Orange', Origin: 'Italy' },
  { ProductName: 'Lemon', Origin: 'Spain' },
  { ProductName: 'Avocado', Origin: 'Chile' },
];
let ret = result
  .sort((x, y) => x.ProductName.localeCompare(y.ProductName))
  .filter((x, i, a) => i > 0 && x.ProductName === a[i - 1].ProductName);
if (!ret.length) ret = result;
console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result=[{ProductName:"Orange",Origin:"Italy"},{ProductName:"Orange",Origin:"Italy"},{ProductName:"Lemon",Origin:"Spain"},{ProductName:"Avocado",Origin:"Chile"}];

const findDuplicates = (arr)  => { 
    let result =[]
    arr.forEach((e,i) => {
        let slice = arr.slice(i+1)
        let dupl = slice.find(n => (n.ProductName === e.ProductName) && (n.Origin === e.Origin))
        if (dupl){
             if(!result.find(n => (n.ProductName === dupl.ProductName) && (n.Origin === dupl.Origin))){
            result.push(dupl)
            }
        }    
    })
    return result
}

console.log(findDuplicates(result))
```